# Having trouble hitting two destinations simultaneously in reverse proxy

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

I have two controllers, and I want to hit both controllers' API at the same time, but my code can hit only once randomly.

How can I achieve this?

**TeaController**

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TeaController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("Test")]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
       return Ok("Tea");
    }
}
```

**BiscuitController**

```cs
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BiscuitController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("Test")]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok("Biscuit");
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "UseCodeBasedConfig": "true",
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "ReverseProxy-route": {
        "ClusterId": "ReverseProxy-cluster",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "ReverseProxy/{**catch-all}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          {
            "PathPattern": "{**catch-all}"
          }

        ]
      }

    },
    "Clusters": {
      "ReverseProxy-cluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "LoadBalancingPolicy": "Random",
          "ReverseProxy-cluster/destination1": {
            "Address": "https://localhost:7044/api/biscuit"
          },
          "ReverseProxy-cluster/destination2": {
            "Address": "https://localhost:7044/api/tea"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var proxyBuilder = builder.Services.AddReverseProxy().LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapReverseProxy();
});


app.Run();
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think its for this yarp: https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have [`LoadBalancingPolicy`](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/load-balancing.html#built-in-policies) specified as `Random`, with both controllers as one of two destinations.  `Random` will unsurprisingly:

> Select a destination randomly.

There doesn't appear to be a way to "hit both at the same time" for the given built in policies.  I would recommend you take a look at the policies to see which fits your need.

Comment: Not only that, but I think you  are fundamentally using Yarp wrong - it seems you'd be routing to the same location (just different controllers), which isn't balancing any kind of load if they end up going to the same host (`https://localhost:7044` in this case).